# I am using python to create a check_html function for validation using a stack

Tags: python, html, stack

I keep coming up with a syntax error:

File "", line 12
else tag == s.peek():
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
def check_html(html_string):
balanced = True
s = Stack()
text_lines = html_string.split("\n")
for line in text_lines:
    # line can be something like <html> or </body>
    if "/" in line: # a close tag
        tag = line.replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace(...)
        if s.is_empty():
            balanced = False
            # should be invalid
          elif tag == s.peek():
            # should be valid and pop
    else:
            # should be invalid
    elif "<" in line: # an open tag
        tag = line.replace("<", "").replace(">", "")
        s.push(tag)
if not s.is_empty():
    # should be invalid
    
return balanced
```

Any input that might lead me in a better direction?

Comment: You really need to fix your indentation. You have an if on one indent level and an else on another.

Answer (score 0):

Try that on line 12. I think you can't write anything in-between 'else' and ':' as if it's another condition, because it's kinda final statement in 'if': it works if anything else above is false.

```
else:
tag == s.peek()
```

Edit

```
def check_html(html_string):
    balanced = True
    s = Stack()
    text_lines = html_string.split("\n")
    for line in text_lines:
        if "/" in line:
            tag = line.replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace(...)
            if s.is_empty():
                balanced = False
            elif (tag == s.peek()):
                some = "some action here"
            else:
                some2 ='some action here again'
        elif "<" in line: # an open tag
            tag = line.replace("<", "").replace(">", "")
            s.push(tag)
        if not s.is_empty():
            return balanced
```

Nope, I did not figure out why and how it works, I just fixed syntax.